# Custom OrderBy in Linq with singly linked entity list

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to come up with an efficient solution to be able to query the entity list and order it correctly. I have created a singly linked list type structure in SQL DB schema.  I am using GUID as my IDs but for simplicity, I'll use int here.  I could solve this problem easily by having a SortOrder column on the DB but because of other requirements, this is how I have to implement this table.

I have a table structure that looks like the following entity model:

```
public class Record
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public int? ChildID;  //References the next record
}
```

My initial thought is to create a partial class like the following:

```
public partial class Record
{
    public int SortOrder
    {
        get
        {
           //query table and loop through the entire list building it from
           //the bottom and keeping count of the integer sort order and return 
           //the one specific to this record
        }
    }
}
```

However, this seems very inefficient to have to query the entire list every time and iterate through to find the SortOrder.  Is there anything else I can leverage  like a custom OrderBy function or anything?  I'm trying sort by the order that would be created when iterating a building the list. For instance, the record with ChildID = null, is the last one in the list, since it does not have a child. I'll start with that record, then get the next one above it that references the previous as its ChildID and go until there is no more in the list that has a reference to ID, which should be when the list is complete and ordered correctly. No two records have the same ChildID.

If I had the following 3 records in a list,

```
ID = 3,  Name = "Apple",  ChildID = 6,
ID = 54, Name = "Orange", ChildID = 3,
ID = 6,  Name = "Banana", ChildID = null
```

Then I would expect to get Orange, Apple, Banana, in that order.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you want to sort by? What order do you want it in?

Comment: If you have a `List<Record> records` variable, you can just do something like: `var sortedRecords = records.OrderBy(r => r.ID);` But it's not clear what you want exactly.

Comment: My apologies, I'm trying sort by the order that would be created when iterating a building the list.  For instance, the record with ChildID = null, is the last one in the list, since it does not have a child.  I'll start with that record, then get the next one above it that references the previous as its ChildID.

Comment: Please update the question with what you are trying to do since not everyone will see your comment. What *exactly* are you sorting? Do you have a `List<Record>` or just a single `Record` that has linked children? What if two records have the same `ChildId`?

Comment: What do you mean by *"the record with ChildID == null"*? GUIDs (and ints) are struct types and cannot be `null`.

Comment: Do you want to try to do this on the SQL server? If you are querying the database and get partial results, could you have fractional portions of the linked list?

Comment: I'd like to do it within the code but I'm not opposed to doing it in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the record ID order is random, and assuming that the `List` you are ordering is complete, or that you won't run out of memory/time if you have to scan the entire table to order the list, I think the best you can do is compute the depth for a `Record` and cache the results:

I am using the `List` as the table, but you could use the table instead if the list you want to order is incomplete:

```
public partial class Record {
    static Dictionary<int, int> depth = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    public int Depth(List<Record> dbTable) {
        int ans = 0;

        var working = new Queue<int>();
        var cur = this;
        do {
            if (depth.TryGetValue(cur.ID, out var curDepth)) {
                ans += curDepth;
                break;
            }
            else {
                working.Enqueue(cur.ID);
                cur = dbTable.FirstOrDefault(r => r.ChildID == cur.ID);
                if (cur != null)
                    ++ans;
            }
        } while (cur != null);

        var workAns = ans;
        while (working.Count > 0) {
            var workingID = working.Dequeue();
            depth.Add(workingID, workAns);
            --workAns;
        }

        return ans;
    }
}
```

**Update:** I re-wrote the code to use a specific queue; my first version was recursive and that was straightforward but risked overflowing the stack and my second version didn't cache the intermediate results when following the linked list which wasn't very efficient. Using a queue of the intermediate IDs ensures I only follow a particular chain depth once.

Now that you have a `Depth` method, sorting is easy:

```
var ans = work.OrderBy(w => w.Depth(work));
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you! I'll test it out in a bit and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @jgabb I added a more efficient version. I don't particularly like its inelegance versus recursion, but couldn't come up with a better way to be efficient.

Comment: I like it.  It looks like its going to be exactly what I need.

Comment: Some testing shows with 100,000 records recursion doesn't blow up but is only about 7% faster, so I think this is good. It is also at least 9 times faster than the previous answer.

Comment: So this cache's it, right? I've noticed when I go and resort the order of records, it keeps the previous sort order.

Comment: @NetMage You seriously? This is extremely inefficient. And static `Dictionary` inside the class - how about multi threading or second time run.

Comment: @IvanStoev suggest how to multi-thread depth in a singly linked list? And using persistent storage is a trade-off at well that depends on factors we don't know, but it can be more inefficient or expensive.

Comment: I meant the whole idea to build "depth" of a linked list element and then order by it is weird. The effort to build the depth (wtf is this - index of the element in the linked list?) is much bigger than creating the linked list. For 100K records your "optimized" algorithm runs in about a minute, while mine (thread safe stateless) runs in milliseconds. And for 1M records your never ends :)

Comment: @IvanStoev It seems like your comment is more aimed at the original question in that case, so it doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: @IvanStoev Interestingly, adding a `recordByNextId` (parent?) `Dictionary` to my code speeds it up to 3x slower than yours, but that would read the entire table which may not be needed. It will complete with 1M records, just takes a while :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to write a method that will return a list in sorted order. You would first find the record with `ChildId == null`, add it to the results list, and then continue to search for items where `item.ChildId == previousItem.Id`, and then insert them at the beginning of the list:

```
private static IEnumerable<Record> OrderRecords(IReadOnlyCollection<Record> records)
{
    // "Exit fast" checks
    if (records == null) return null;
    if (records.Count < 2) return records.ToList();

    // Get last record and add it to our results
    Record currentRecord = records.Single(r => r.ChildID == null);
    var results = new List<Record> {currentRecord};

    // Keep getting the parent reference to the previous record 
    // and insert it at the beginning of the results list
    while ((currentRecord = records.SingleOrDefault(r => 
        r.ChildID == currentRecord.ID)) != null)
    {
        results.Insert(0, currentRecord);
    }

    return results;
}
```

In use, this would look something like:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var records = new List<Record>
    {
        new Record {ID = 3, Name = "Apple", ChildID = 6},
        new Record {ID = 54, Name = "Orange", ChildID = 3},
        new Record {ID = 6, Name = "Banana", ChildID = null}
    };

    var sortedRecords = OrderRecords(records);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", sortedRecords.Select(r => r.Name)));

    Console.Write("\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: While this may not be exactly what I was looking for, I may be able to leverage this and make it work.  Thanks! I'll give it a shot in a bit and let you know how it ends up!

Comment: If list is really big then using temporary `Dictionary<int, Record>` could speed up the chaining.

Answer (score 1):

The best algorithm for this task is to prepare a fast lookup data structure (like `Dictionary`) of `Record` by `ChildID`. Then the ordered result can be produced backwards starting with `ChildID = null` and using the record `ID` to find the previous record.

Since the hash lookup time complexity is O(1), the time complexity of the algorithm is linear O(N) - the fastest possible.

Here is the implementation:

```
static Record[] Ordered(IEnumerable<Record> records)
{
    var recordByNextId = records.ToDictionary(e => e.ChildID.Wrap());
    var result = new Record[recordByNextId.Count];
    int? nextId = null;
    for (int i = result.Length - 1; i >=0; i--)
        nextId = (result[i] = recordByNextId[nextId]).ID;
    return result;
}
```

The explanation of `e.ChildID.Wrap()` custom extension method. I wish I can use simply `e.ChildID`, but the BCL `Dictionary` class throws annoying exception for `null` key. To overcome that limitation in general, I use a simple wrapper `struct` and "fluent" helper:

```
public struct ValueWrapper<T> : IEquatable<ValueWrapper<T>>
{
    public readonly T Value;
    public ValueWrapper(T value) => Value = value;
    public bool Equals(ValueWrapper<T> other) => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(Value, other.Value);
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is ValueWrapper<T> other && Equals(other);
    public override int GetHashCode() => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.GetHashCode(Value);
    public static implicit operator ValueWrapper<T>(T x) => new ValueWrapper<T>(x);
    public static implicit operator T(ValueWrapper<T> x) => x.Value;
}

public static class ValueWrapper
{
    public static ValueWrapper<T> Wrap<T>(this T value) => new ValueWrapper<T>(value);
}
```

Comment: How would i use this in a linq query?

Comment: Well, like any custom method.  You can even put it in a public static class, change the signature to `public static Record[] Ordered(this IEnumerable<Record> records)`, in other words, turn it to custom extension method. Then you can use like any LINQ to Objects method, e.g. (following the style of other answer) `var ans = work.Ordered();`. The main focus here is the performance - for 100,000 records this executes in milliseconds.

Comment: Another way to handle null key is to *not* put it in dictionary and just save it on the side.

Comment: @Dialecticus Sure, but that adds complexity to the code which I think is not worth. Another way is to eliminate the nullable by using the `default` (`0`, `Guid.Empty` etc) as `null` substitute if it's not allowed in the keys. And finally, in my projects I use custom `Dictionary` implementation which has no such limitations :) Interestingly, `Lookup` has no such requirement either.

Comment: While very fast, this doesn't seem to handle partial `List`s from a larger database. I also wonder how optimal it is with a database in general. I also get a type conflict on `class ValueWrapper` and `struct ValueWrapper<T>` but that might be my environment.